# Selenium-manager.exe window popping up

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

While trying to setup a headless browser using selenium a console window pops up briefly before it closes, it's not the chromedriver.exe window cause that's handled by `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` the window is called selenium-manager.exe.

It only pops up when I build my script into an executable with Pyinstaller cause when I run it normally with Python it doesn't appear. The command I used was `pyinstaller --windowed my_script.py`, I also tried adding `--noconsole` and using `--noconsole` alone but nothing worked. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Operation System: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0, Python: 3.11.1, Selenium: 4.10.0, Pyinstaller: 5.13.0

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

def setup_options(options: ChromeOptions) -> ChromeOptions :
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    return options

def setup_driver() -> Chrome:
    service_chrome = Service()
    service_chrome.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    options = setup_options(ChromeOptions())
    return Chrome(service=service_chrome, options=options)

driver = setup_driver()
# Do some automated work
driver.quit()
```

Here's a screenshot of the window:

[image: selenium-manager.exe window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

I made a merged [pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12435) with the fix. This bug should only be present in selenium versions 4.10.0 and below.

Hacky fix, navigate to the following path in your virtual environment ".venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py".

Within the script, there's a method called `run` in the `SeleniumManager` class that starts a `subprocess` that executes the selenium-manager.exe they made an over-sight and assumed everyone would be running their scripts in a console environment or maybe didn't consider windows users, so when making the call to `subprocess.run` they didn't add `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Edit it as follows

```
            if sys.platform == "win32":
                completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
            else: 
                completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that the bug is only present in windows. They'll probably address it in the next updates.

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid this by referring to the Chromedriver explicitly when starting the Chromeservice.

In this example, I found the path needs to be an absolute path, not a relative one. Maybe you can probably get it to work with a relative path

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

import sys
import os

def get_path(relative_path):
    """ Get the absolute path to the resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def setup_options(options: ChromeOptions) -> ChromeOptions:
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    return options


def setup_driver() -> Chrome:
    service_chrome = Service((get_path('C:/absolute/path/to/driver/chromedriver.exe')))
    service_chrome.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    options = setup_options(ChromeOptions())
    return Chrome(service=service_chrome, options=options)


driver = setup_driver()
# Do some automated work
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I've done some more digging, within my venv in the selenium library directory there's the selenium-manager.exe file ".venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe", this seems to be the culprit, but I need it to setup the driver instance.

Comment: Just tried again, and I can reproduce it. But the selenium-manager.exe window only flickers open and closes immediately, is it the same for you or it stays open?

Comment: Yeah it flickers, but the problem is that I'm developing a gui app so even that brief flickering is a no no. I've found a hacky fix though, I navigated to the following path: ".venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py" . There's a method called ```run``` in the ```SeleniumManager``` class that starts a subprocess that executes the selenium-manager.exe but I guess they assumed everyone would be using selenium in a console so when making the call to ```subprocess.run``` they didn't add ```creation_flags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW``` so I added it and it doesn't show up now.

Comment: I found a solution. I will edit answer

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in my opinion the problem with this fix, is that when the user doesn't have the chromedriver, then selenium will raise an exception, I prefer using selenium-manager cause even if it doesn't find the chromedriver it can gracefully attempt to install the appropriate version. I guess you could attempt to bundle it within the distributable but this brings another problem in that it's not future-proof, what if the version bundled gets outdated.

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to bundle it with the distribution.